# Benefit of defining global variable over local, in respect to memory management

Tags: java, oop, memory-management

In java we know the different scope of class level and method level variables.

I want to have a better idea of memory managment.

can any one tell me what is the benefit of using method justAnyMethod1 over justAnyMethod2 (with respect to memory management) if there is any?

```
public class MyClass {

    Emp e;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass mca=new MyClass();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        mca.justAnyMethod1();
        mca.justAnyMethod2();
    }
    }

    void justAnyMethod1(){
        e=new Emp(1,1000,"Edge");
    }
    void justAnyMethod2(){
        Emp l=new Emp(1,1000,"Edge");
    }


}


class Emp {

    int id=0;
    int sal=0;
    String addr="";

    public Emp() {}

    public Emp(int id, int sal, String addr) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.sal = sal;
        this.addr = addr;
    }


}
```

Thanks !

As for justAnyMethod2(), whenever the method is done, the object is eligible for garbage collection, but we all know there is no guarantee, when it will happen. so if the program runs every second, it will end up creating many objects, in the pool, will it be the same in case of justAnyMethod1() also?? If yes, any other way to avoid it?

Comment: `justAnyMethod2` does nothing.  It creates a new `Emp`, which then immediately goes out of scope and will get garbage collected.  Please review the Java tutorials.

Comment: Don't worry about memory, just make sure your program works correctly. Memory is easy to get, competent programmers aren't.

Comment: @Jim As for justAnyMethod2(), whenever the method is done, the object is eligible for garbage collection, but we all know there is no guarantee, when it will happen. so if the program runs every second, it will end up creating many objects, in the pool, will it be the same in case of justAnyMethod1() also?? If yes, any other way to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure about your perticular scenario , but

if it was like

```
public class MyClass {

    Emp e=new Emp();
```

then it will be declared and instantiated at the class level, and every method method call will keep on overwriting it , instead of allocating new space for a new object.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding memory use, the only difference between those two functions is after running `justAnyMethod1()`, `Emp e` will remain initialised for as long as the main method is running. The second method creates a local instance of Emp, initialises it, then destroys it once the function returns, since it was created inside the scope of `justAnyMethod2()`, it will not survive beyond that function.

The only real difference memory-wise here is where each object is stored, as I understand it global variables are stored in a separate part of the heap and not stored in the stack, which is where your mca object is stored.

Comment: Contrary to the question’s title, there is no global variable in the example code. `mca` is a local variable of the `main` method and therefore stored on the stack. But the question is about the `e` variable which is an instance field and hence, stored on the heap, unless the optimizer figures out that the only reference to the containing object is by a local variable and eliminates it. Note that even if there was a global variable, it only contained a *reference* to an object that still resides in the heap.

Comment: I never said it was a global variable, I'm answering his question about global vs local variables after talking about the difference between what he's done in this example.

Comment: You second part starts with *The only real difference memory-wise here is* which does not indicate that you are now not talking about the examples anymore. In fact, the word *here* suggests that you are talking exactly about the same as before. Besides that, as already said, that second part is fundamentally wrong as the storage of *objects* does not depend on what kind of *reference variable* point to them.

Comment: Yes, the first sentence refers to the difference between the examples here, the second part refers to the difference between that and global variables in which I made a mistake in and have now corrected, I was not in any way saying that 'e' is a global variable.